# how to recognize color intensities in an image using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

From a given image ,i would like to know if it contains more of green, red or blue component
 and its proportion to each other.
its output should be like - a given image has more of green component and in proportion to ===
with red and blue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple script that finds the average red, green, and blue signal in an image:

```
img = imread('image_name.jpg')
red_mean = mean(mean(img(:,:,1)))   %the first channel is red
green_mean = mean(mean(img(:,:,2)))   %the second channel is green
blue_mean = mean(mean(img(:,:,2)))   %the third channel is blue
```

From here, determining the proportions should be straightforward.

Note: I've only tested this with a JPG. TIFs will be different because they store multi-layer images